# How to make filter products on laravel correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have scope on my model Product:

```
public function scopeAttrSearch($query, $ids)
{
    $query->whereHas('attribute.attribute', function ($q) use ($ids) {
        foreach ($ids as $category => $values) {
            $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $values);
        }
    });

    return $query;
}
```

And I have filters on page with multiple checkboxes. Each group checkboxes have a category of filter. When user click on checkboxes I send `id` category of filter and `id` value of this checkbox. Variable `ids` have this structure:

```
array:2 [ 
    1 => array:2 [ 
            0 => "1" 
            1 => "3" 
    ],

    3 => array:2 [ 
        0 => "5" 
        1 => "6" 
    ] 
 ]
```

Where `1` and `3` id of category filters. And arrays to them - this is id values checkboxes of filter.

On controller I call this scope:

```
    if (@$request->data['attrs']) {
        $_products = $_products->attrSearch($request->data['attrs']);
    }
```

And return on page already filtered products in template:

```
return $_products;
```

I have a problem. Filter working. But if I check checkboxes from different categories I get empty results. If I check checkboxes from same category - all working, I get filtered products. How I can fix this problem with different category?

Model relations in Product:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductAttribute');
}
```

ProductAttribute:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AttributeValue', 'attribute_value_id');
}
```

Category id of filter have column `attribute_id`

Comment: Can you post your code illustrating the relationships between the relevant models, together with the local and foreign keys.

Comment: @fubar done.....

Comment: So are the ids indexing the `$ids` array for the `Attribute` model, and the ids within the array for the `AttributeValue` model?

Comment: @fubar yes, all right

Comment: Firstly, your scope is returning the original `$query` which came into the function, not the functionality you've added within the function. Either save the `whereHas()` query into a variable and return it, or just return the `$query` itself straight away.

Comment: I need filter category and values